# Problem sending mail with attachment using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am using Angular. When I send a mail with attachment to email, the response was that I received the data code of the file instead its actual file format.
like this:

[image]

I don't know what's the problem.

here's the code : 
html :

```
<div class="uploadfile">
<input fileread="formData.attached" (change)="onFileSelected" type="file" id="real-file" hidden="hidden" />
<button type="button" id="custom-button">Upload CV</button>
<span id="custom-text">No file chosen, yet.</span>
</div>

<!--Script upload -->
<script>
const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
const customBtn = document.getElementById("custom-button");
const customTxt = document.getElementById("custom-text");

customBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  realFileBtn.click();
  });

realFileBtn.addEventListener("change", function() {
     if (realFileBtn.value) {
    customTxt.innerHTML = realFileBtn.value.match(
      /[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/
     )[1];
     } else {
      customTxt.innerHTML = "No file chosen, yet.";
        }
    });
    </script>
<!--End of Script upload -->
```

app.js :

```
myApp.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Hope you can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the image you attached, I saw that the file is actually 64 based string. So the problem is from your Angular Code.

```
reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
```

readAsDataURL will return the base64 encoded string. You can check the link here [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

As the result, you just receive the string in your email, but not actual file. So you should specify file name and encoding = base64.

I'm not sure that technology in the back end that you are using. You can check the sample nodeJs code here.

```js
const mailOptions = {
  ...
  attachments: [
    {   // encoded string as an attachment
      filename: yourFileName,
      content: fileString,
      encoding: 'base64'
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for answering, I'm still new in coding maybe you can also check my backend code here : 


     $scope.formData = {
        type:'careers',
        name : '',
        contact : '',
        email : '',
        position : '',
        attached : '',
        
    };

I still don't make it work :(, Thank you so much!